# Why has my XPATH locator suddenly stopped working?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

1. 0-415 Builds have passed
2. 416-550 have failed
3. The following locator use to work:

   ```
   public @FindBy(xpath = ".//*[@id='menu']/ul//a[@href='/driving-experiences']") WebElement link_DrivingExperiences;
   ```
4. Now suddenly it has stopped working, I have tried using the absolute XPATH and that works; which im trying to avoid, i intend to use dynamic locators.
5. My click method:

   ```
   public void waitAndClickElement(WebElement element) throws InterruptedException {
   boolean clicked = false;
   int attempts = 0;
   while (!clicked && attempts < 3) {
       try {
           this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).click();
           System.out.println("Successfully clicked on the WebElement: " + "<" + element.toString() + ">");
           clicked = true;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Unable to wait and click on WebElement, Exception: " + e.getMessage());
           Assert.fail("Unable to wait and click on the WebElement, using locator: " + "<" + element.toString() + ">");
       }
       attempts++;
   }
   ```

   }
6. HTML Element:
   [image]

Comment: What means "stopped working"? Does it give `NoSuchElementException` now or doesn't fire any event? I try to avoid XPath and use CssSelector instead. Once normally you can find elements in a shorter way, changes in the DOM do not break your tests so easily with CssSelector.

Comment: Considering provided `HTML` your `XPath` seem to be ok. Share exception log

Comment: Please post the HTML as text instead of an image. It makes it easier for potential answerers to use and read. Have you tried something simple like `By.linkText("Driving")` or `By.cssSelector("a[href='/driving-experiences']")`? You are probably seeing the effects of XPaths that are too deeply nested. It's hard to say without the before and after HTML, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for link text which most probably won't be changed in the long run

```
//a[text()='Driving'] or
//a[contains(text(),'Driving')]
```

Use case 2 if link text 'Driving' in your case contains leading or trailing white-spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like...

`public @FindBy(xpath = "//a[contains(@class, 'toplevellink') and contains(@href, 'driving-experiences')]"))`

Cheers,